# A bjection between two stochastic processes

Tags: markov-chains, stochastic-processes

Let x(t) be a Markov process. We define the stochastic process y(t) such that :

```
y(t) = x(f(t))

f : T -> T
```

T is the parameter set of the process x(t).

If we know that f is bijective, is y(t) a Markov process ?

Comment: What assumptions are you putting on the index set T and the function f?

Comment: Only if f is affine.  To see why, try applying the change of variables theorem.  In order for the coefficients for the process to be constant, the function f must be at most first order.

Comment: @Mikola: if the function f is a strictly increasing function and not affine ...

Comment: See http://books.google.com/books?id=_gOMJL5AEdQC&pg=PA99

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If f is continuous, differentiable and strictly increasing, the answer is yes. It is easy to see that y(t_n) is conditionally independent of y(t_1), y(t_2), y(t_{n-2}) given y(t_{n-1}), as this is the equivalent property enjoyed by x(t) when it is Markov. x(\tilde{t}_n}) is independent of x(\tilde{t}*1),...,x(\tilde{t}*{n-2})  conditional on x(\tilde{t}_{n-1})  as long as the \tilde{t}_k form a strictly increasing sequence.

Comment: Funny: neither *continuous*, nor *differentiable* nor *strictly* are necessary.